# How to export and import data from a Postgres database with Hasura?

Tags: postgresql, hasura

I have Hasura GraphQL engine running on a Docker container. My goal is to export all the data from my Postgres database so that my coworker can import it and work with the same data. What is the correct way to do this with Hasura?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally do like the normal database on docker, nothing different, you can use any kind of `dump` or import/export.
You should understand the way Hasura works, it just take database as an input, Hasura does not take the database installation process.